# Someone to explain the mechanics for DSL language creation "in plain english"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dsl, dsl-tools, vsix

Basically the problem is that I'm starting doing somme development of Visual Studio 2010 extensions and language definitions are rather complex, so anyone giving a small intro and pointing some good docs would be great

Thanks in advance,

**EDIT** My basic problem is that I want to define a simple language to create some models on Visual Studio 2k10 and generate some source code using such models. The problem is where can I find some nice books, or do I have to dig into MSDN to unveil the mask... :)

Again, thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? The text of your question doesn't mention the DSL tools, for instance, so it's unclear what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried starting with the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126259.aspx)? If you found this difficult to start with, how could we make it easier to follow?

Comment: Nice link, but I'm actually looking for some books, blogs or something else, seems like I'm having to dig into MSDN though...